# Web App Architecture With SSL and Without SSL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-applications

Is it normal to divide a web app as:

```
http://webapp.com
```

and

```
https://app.webapp.com or https://secure.webapp.com
```

when SSL is needed?

I'm thinking in creating 2 differenr apps, one sinatra to host all the static pages, and one rails with SSL to host all the dynamic content. Is that correct thinking?

Thanks

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve by dividing the app into two?

Comment: Now slowing down the home page with processing work for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't want to maintain two apps if I didn't have to.  Rails offers built-in caching that I would try first (page caching, action caching, and fragment caching).  As far as SSL, from the digging around I've been doing recently, the common recommendation seems to be if you have data that needs to be secured, put your entire app behind SSL since it protects you from certain exploits and doesn't really have a significant impact on performance.